# Robotium isn't scrolling to a text view

Tags: android, testing, robotium

I have the following layout in my fragment and activity:

[image]

As you can see, Robotium fills in the text for the `EditText` views. It also scrolls to and fills in the "Team" field which follows the "Player Name". However, there is a `Spinner` after that, with an appropriate label in a `textView`, and `solo.searchForText()` doesn't scroll down to put it into view. Is this because of the split Action Bar? What can I do to remedy this problem in my tests?

The relevant code that attempts to access the `Spinner`:

```
        Spinner playerPositionSpinner = (Spinner) solo.getView(R.id.player_position_text);
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> playerPositionAdapter = (ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>) playerPositionSpinner
                .getAdapter();
        int newIndex = playerPositionAdapter.getPosition(card
                .getPlayerPosition());
        int currIndex = playerPositionSpinner.getSelectedItemPosition();

        boolean isPositionVisible = solo.searchText(
                solo.getString(R.string.player_position_label), true);
        solo.waitForView(R.id.player_position_text);

        boolean isConditionVisible = solo.searchText(solo.getString(R.string.condition_label),
                false);
        int index = -1;
        if (!isConditionVisible && isPositionVisible) {
            index = 0;
        }
        if (isPositionVisible && isConditionVisible) {
            index = 1;
        }

        Assert.assertFalse("Invalid index", index == -1);
        solo.pressSpinnerItem(index, newIndex - currIndex);
```

The XML layout for the form fragment:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@id/scroll_card_details"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:stretchColumns="1" >

        <TableRow>

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@id/autograph"
                android:text="@string/autograph_label"
                android:layout_span="2" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow>

            <TextView
                android:text="@string/condition_label"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@id/condition"
                android:hint="@string/condition_hint"
                android:singleLine="true" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow>

            <TextView
                android:text="@string/brand_label"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <AutoCompleteTextView
                android:id="@id/brand_text"
                android:completionThreshold="1"
                android:hint="@string/brand_hint"
                android:inputType="textCapWords"
                android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
                android:singleLine="true" >

                <requestFocus />
            </AutoCompleteTextView>
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow>

            <TextView
                android:text="@string/year_label"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@id/year_text"
                android:hint="@string/year_hint"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
                android:singleLine="true" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow>

            <TextView
                android:text="@string/number_label"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@id/number_text"
                android:hint="@string/number_hint"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
                android:singleLine="true" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow>

            <TextView
                android:text="@string/value_label"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@id/value_text"
                android:hint="@string/value_hint"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
                android:singleLine="true" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow>

            <TextView
                android:text="@string/count_label"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@id/count_text"
                android:hint="@string/count_hint"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
                android:singleLine="true" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow>

            <TextView
                android:text="@string/player_name_label"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <AutoCompleteTextView
                android:id="@id/player_name_text"
                android:completionThreshold="1"
                android:hint="@string/player_name_hint"
                android:inputType="textCapWords"
                android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
                android:singleLine="true" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow>

            <TextView
                android:text="@string/team_label"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <AutoCompleteTextView
                android:id="@id/team_text"
                android:completionThreshold="1"
                android:hint="@string/team_hint"
                android:inputType="textCapWords"
                android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
                android:singleLine="true" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow>

            <TextView
                android:text="@string/player_position_label"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@id/player_position_text"
                android:hint="@string/player_position_hint"
                android:singleLine="true" />
        </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently Robotium finds the Ad, instead of the ScrollView. Robotium doesn't know how to deal with it and just ignores it instead of causing any error.

I ending up writing my own function to do the scrolling:

```
public static void scrollDown(final ScrollView scrollView) {
    scrollView.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            scrollView.arrowScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_DOWN);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I was having the same issue, here is what I did:

`solo.sendKey(Solo.DOWN);
solo.sendKey(Solo.DOWN);
solo.sendKey(Solo.DOWN);`

Comment: solo.sendKey(Solo.DOWN) did the trick for me. Thanks @GabrielKaffka.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
solo.pressSpinnerItem(0, 1);
```

The first parameter is the index of the spinner to use and the second parameter is the item in the spinner to select.

Comment: A static index doesn't work because I want my test to be flexible for many screen sizes. On larger screens, there may two visible spinners.

Comment: On smaller screens, the spinner I want to click on may be hidden. When I do `pressSpinnerItem(1, x)`, I get "Two Spinners not found!"